# Can't pass arguments to pandoc through rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to pass `pandoc` arguments through `rmarkdown` YAML as it is linked here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#advanced-customization

and the [option](http://pandoc.org/README.html#options) I am trying to add is code line numbering:

> --indented-code-classes=CLASSES
>
> Specify classes to use for indented code blocks–for example, perl,numberLines or haskell. Multiple classes may be separated by spaces or commas.

My `.Rmd` file is below but after the rendering the output do no look like to be numbered. Does anyone know how to pass this argument correctly? I've tried many various possibilities but none of them worked.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Marcin Kosinski"
date: "28.12.2015"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: espresso
    md_extensions: +fenced_code_attributes+fenced_code_blocks
    pandoc_args: [
      "--indented-code-classes","numberLines"
    ]
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r, results='hide'}
summary(cars)
iris
summary(iris)
```
````

Comment: The option you are trying to use is for *indented* code blocks. Knitr chunks are a different kind of blocks, and are not indented. You can easily verify this by adding a line starting with 4 spaces outside of a chunk.

Comment: Do you think is it even possible to somehow number lines in knitr using rmarkdown and pandoc, specifing somehow global options?

Comment: It might be possible to do this with a custom CSS, adding line numbers to `<div class="sourceCode">`, if your only intended output format is html. In that case, you should rephrase the question and tag it as css, or ask another one.